How should on-topic question be moved to this SE?
Assume a question, as asked and phrased, is in the intersection of the topics for this SE and another. Both would consider it on-topic. It's first asked in another SE, but then later the OP realizes that the expertise in this SE is more useful.
What is the correct way to "move" the question to this SE from another without running afoul of the no x-posting policy?

The specific context is where I'm trying to remember a specific psychology term and first asked on the english SE (because it's the term uses English words) but then realized that it would be better as a question on this SE.

Or is that question off-topic even ignoring the fact I first asked it somewhere else?

Questions involving multiple sites are better asked on the global MSE - examples: What is migration and how does it work? and How do I move my own question to another Stack Exchange site?

This question is about what the people here think (the global opinion is irrelevant to this question). If the local opinion is that you don't care enough to have an opinion other than the global one, that would be a valid answer.

You got some excellent answers on English SE. The only reason those answers don't answer "your" question is because you don't recognize any of them as the terminology you are looking for. But note that the purpose of Stack Exchange is to provide meaningful questions and answers to not just you, but anyone that may come after you. Other people with the same question might in fact be thinking of one of the terms already posted there.
The current answers not being meaningful to you is not a reason to move the question. If you would treat it as such, the question should in essence be closed as not being useful to anyone else but the OP.
Instead, focus on this: you seem to have some reason to believe posting the question here would lead to you finding your answer. Why is that? As Chris Rogers commented already:

Cross posting is asking exactly the same question in more than one site. What you can do is ask a Psychology related question here and an English Language question (non psychology) in English.SE

You can post a psychology-related question here, and tailor it to this community's guidelines (i.e., include initial research; the English SE question could actually constitute "initial research"). Highlight how the question on English SE is different than here. E.g., are you only interested in terminology as it is used in scientific literature of a certain field? Maybe you can provide more background information on where you encountered the term before? Maybe it was in a research article? What type of research did that article focus on? Etc.
Once you edit the question as such, it can be reopened here. No need to migrate the English SE question here. It is a good question and fully belongs there.

My impression is they've probably heard a phrase used that's just someone using language to describe something, perhaps creatively, not a specific term at all. I do not think their question will fare any better here than it did on English.

That the first question provides value on English.SE is a good argument for that question being kept. That that SE was unable to provide the value I am seeking is either an argument for seeking the same information elsewhere (here) or that SEs in general aren't interested in helping me. -- The fact of the matter is that the question I want to ask is independent of where I'm asking it. Asking the same question using different phrasing as you are suggesting still seems to me like you suggesting I dodge around your rules. I'm generally uncomfortable abiding by rules while defying their intent.

@BCS It may be reasonable to ask here about a psychological phenomenon and to try to find the terminology you should use to find further reading on that topic; I don't think that's dodging rules. It's not reasonable, however, to ask that we come up with a particular phrase you heard one time.

The question has received 2 answers over there and therefore migration or deletion of the Q is at this time difficult. The Q is rightfully closed over here (although apparently for another reason, I wasn't involved in the closure), since there are 2 answers over there. Why the post is locked there may well have to do with cross posting.
The best thing to do is flagging the question for mod attention after posting, but before cross posting. Let the mods handle it from that point. Link this post in the flag comment.
Ideally, mods of other sites migrate questions after discussing it behind the scenes. Often however, that doesn't happen and asking about it in meta, or in chat is a great thing to do.
